# Can I relate a non-calendar entry to a Solspace Calendar?

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

I have a site with EE6 and Solspace EE Calendar 4. I have a single Events channel where all events are published. I have 15+ calendars set up in EE Calendar for various programs represented on the site.

I want to allow our publishers to associate a non-event/non-calendar entry (which represents a single page on the website) with a specific calendar in the addon. The goal is to be able to create a mini-calendar and list upcoming events, filtered to a specific calendar/program, on the page template for the non-event/non-calendar entry.

I'm struggling with the best way to associate a non-event entry with one of the calendars in EE Calendar so that I can use this relationship in the template tag parameters to create a mini-cal or event list.

I could add a new field where publishers enter the calendar id or calendar shortname, but this seems clunky as they would need to look up that info in the control panel ahead of time. I could add a new EE Calendar field, but this field is designed to capture date & time of an event and not really designed to just establish a relationship to a specific calendar.

Does anyone have an idea which would make this relationship more seamless and user friendly? Maybe I'm missing something simple by thinking the solution needs to be complicated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have many 'single pages' (i.e. less than a few dozen) on the site I'd look at adding a relationship field in the events channel. When you create an event you'd select one or more pages to relate to. That would give you the ability to bi-direction linking to/from those pages.